# Automated check for question quality

Tags: feature-request, support, asking-questions

What would cause a question to receive the following message:

Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
It does not meet our quality standards.

(When I added a few words to my question, it was accepted, so I'm guessing my original question was too short.  Still, it would be helpful to have a more specific error message.)

Answer (score 5):

It's not *just* length; several other heuristics contribute to a question's "quality score", and if it scores too low, we block it. *Usually*, this works out well - questions that fail too many checks are in dire need of cleanup, and giving the author a chance to do this before posting saves *everyone* time and grief.

However, there *are* edge-cases where the system falls on its face. If you can't get around the problem by doing a bit of cleanup on your text, you can always ask us to take a look at it.

And yes, the message *could* be more specific, but that would defeat the purpose - we don't *want* folks to just pad out their questions until they get through, we're hoping they put a bit more thought into what they're asking.

#### Further reading: [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)